# iOS - contacts enable/disable ( privacy setting) changes reflection same as WhatsApp?

Tags: ios, permissions, contacts, whatsapp, privacy

I am working on a chat application same as **whatsapp**. So I need same functionality when user disable/enable contact access (**privacy setting**) for my app.  If the user disable or enable the contact in app setting. How can I be notify in the app. I need to keep track when user changes enable/disable contact settings (privacy setting). So i do reflect changes on each event in My App.
And if anyone knows how whatsapp doing this.

**Given below is the screenshots of whatsapp.**

Case 1.**Has Contact Access**

[image: whatsapp when has contacts access]

Case 2 **Don't Have Contact Access**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Every time the user launch the app you can check if the app has still permission to the contacts with the following code:

```
  #import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

  ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

  if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
      if (granted) {
          // First time access has been granted
         // Show 4 Tabs
      } else {
          // User denied access
          // Show 3 Tabs
      }
    });
  }
  else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // The user has previously given access, add the contact
    // Show 4 Tabs

  }
  else {
    // The user has denied access
    // Show only 3 Tabs
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Manuel, thanks for the quick response . I know about this. But I want to know if there is any delegate, notification or observer to notifiy App about authorization changes.

Comment: Manuel -if you know how can i regenerate the pop up that your apps want to access your contact. I want to regenerate this. But that only comes once. if you know how to regenerate the pop up

Answer (score -1):

As per apple's website (scroll down to Privacy in the middle of the page), access to the address book must be granted before it can be access programmatically.Here is what I ended up doing-

```
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

- (BOOL)isContactsFetchingAccessibleOrNot {
  // Request authorization to Address Book
  ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

  if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
      if (granted) {
          // First time access has been granted, add the contact
          //do something
      } else {
          // User denied access
          // Display an alert telling user the contact could not be added
      }
    });
  }
  else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // The user has previously given access, add the contact
    //do something
  }
  else {
    // The user has previously denied access
    // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
  }
}
```

You can also call this method when app comes from background to foreground.